# Teamsite component or template

Tags: content-management-system, teamsite

I was wondering if page templates can be built instead of individual components in Teamsite 7? I've seen other cMS systems where it is just a page template that has lots of functionality built I and you can "switch" on and off elements that you want to display instead of having to drag components onto a page? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but since I just came across it:

Yes, TeamSite supports templates (.template) files which can be partial or full page templates. The default location is iwadmin/main/livesite/template.

I recommend downloading the developer guides from Autonomy's web site for detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Templates in teamsite/livesite is like a bag that can contain components. But in order for a functionality to be developed in teamsite/livesite we need to create components. certainly we can avoid dragging and dropping components in each page by creating templates and dropping components within it for once. Keep in mind templates are bound to layouts. for each type of layout we need to create a template. Please have a look at TS_7.3_SiteDeveloper_rev1, Chapter 5.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create templates instead of dragging components.
Since, TeamSite supports templates (.template) files which can be partial or full page templates and resides at location : iwadmin/main/livesite/template.
So, whenever you try to create a new page everytime the HTML code required for that page gets automatically added with the template and layouts you selected.
But, again this is not good since you can have any number of templates you need but this could create confusions at times when you try to create a new page since you will need to remember every template name and contents that you will need for a particular page so it's better to have small lists of templates and layouts since then we can say that there is reusability in our application/website which we are going to develop using Teamsite and Livesite.

Please vote the solution if its helpful.

**Thanks!**